# GData not compiling with Apple LLVM 4.1

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, gdata

I am using gdata-objectivec-client-1.10.0 in my application. I am try to build an iOS 6 and iphone 5 supported version. Now the problem is when i compiling app with Apple llvm 4.1 then it gives error given below. But when i compile it with LLVM GCC 4.2 then it compile with out error and app works fine. Can anyone guide me how to solve this problem.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check out the current version of the library using the command shown at

https://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/source/checkout

If you are building the library sources directly into your project, you will need to remove the old source file references and add the current files. For example, the `GDataOAuthAuthentication` file shown above is for authenticating via OAuth 1, an authentication method no longer supported by the library.

Most of the APIs formerly accessed via the Google Data APIs library have been deprecated; some have been replaced by newer JSON APIs accessible with the Google APIs Client Library at

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/